# In Xamarin Test Cloud, how to run concurrent tests on multiple devices for an app that uses logged in users?

Tags: testing, xamarin, cloud, coded-ui-tests

*Test case:*

User books a hotel room. The user status changes to *booked_room*. This room will become unavailable for other users logged in at the same time. After booking the room, user performs other tasks based on the booked room.

*The problem is:*

If we run this test on multiple devices simultaneously with the same user account, the test will pass only on the first device. When test runs on second device, the app will request the user status and won't show the rooms list because user already selected one on previous device, causing the test to fail because the REPL couldn't find any room on the elements tree.

Every single test of my suite starts with the login process.

Have you faced to this problem using Xamarin Test Cloud? Should I implement a server-side solution to create a database instance every time the test suite is about to run?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem that is not only related to the testcloud. The repeatability of tests is always a problem when a database / shared resource is involved ^^

The answer depends on what you want to achieve with these UI Tests.

A **possibility** would be to distinguish between integration test and UI test.

- **Integration:**

  - Test the Web API and the consumer
  - Services that consume your API are executed as Unit tests
- **UI:**

  - Test the visual appearance (and App logic)
  - Mock the services for the UI tests (use `BookingServiceMock` instead of `BookingService` for `IBookingService`) I hope you are using dependency injection :) The Advantage of this approach is, that you can use [Backdoors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/) to control your mock (e.g. simulate error cases).

The disadvantage are:

- You have no system test, because the App never talks with the actual backend.
- Your App under test differs from the App in the App store (on iOS it is normal, because you link the test runner library into the app)

You could solve this with a separate Testsuite that is executed after the integration and UI tests just on one Android device and then on one iOS device.

Comment: I'm using a service class (the one that actually perform the api calls) defined in the Shared Project code that is instantiated and called from the Android and iOS projects. What I understand from your answer is that I should create a database mock locally on each device every time the test suite is executed?

Comment: No I'd replace the Implementation of the service class with a mock (that just returns data as like you want). So you can simulate every scenario without writing stuff to the database / calling your webservice.

Comment: UITest and Calabash (iOS and Android) have support `backdoor` calls to your app.  It is common to use these `backdoor` calls to put your app into a good state for testing.  In this case you could implement a backdoor that does what Sven-Michael Stübe suggests.

Comment: I going to end up doing what you suggested on your comment, @Sven-MichaelStübe. Seems to be the most suitable solution for my case.

Answer (score 2):

For a relatively simple approach (depending on your app and test code), you can have each concurrent test (device) use a different set of user credentials and book different rooms. In your test code you would then have some collection of user credentials, room numbers and other variables that should vary per concurrent test.

Xamarin Test Cloud has an environment variable `XTC_DEVICE_INDEX`:

> This is a string in the range of 0 to N-1, where N is the number of
> devices the test is run on. This variable is useful in situations
> where the same test is being run in parallel on multiple devices. The
> value of XTC_DEVICE_INDEX is unique for each test script executing on
> a specific device.
> [Xamarin Test Cloud Environment Variables](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/apis/environment_variables/)

This works if you only have one test run executing (on multiple devices) at a time. If a second set of tests start before the first finished it would try to use the same set of variables as the first set of tests. If you need to support this you could provide a web service that allows your test code to check-out the user credentials (and other associated variables) or a key or index to use to pick the right values from those embedded in your test code.